Trouble running ROS2 launch files from a non-interactive SSH command
I am writing a program that is supposed to remotely run ROS2 launch files on a connected robot via SSH. I am using Golang to connect to the robot via SSH and run ROS2 commands. So far this setup has worked, I have been able to run ROS2 commands such as
ros2 topic list and ros2 topic info, and they have returned the expected output. When I try to run a ros2 launch file however, no output is returned, and running commands on the robot to try and detect if the node is running (ros2 node list) show that the launched nodes are not running.
My code for executing SSH commands via go is:
func (serverMsg *BaseWSServerMsg) executeArbitrarySSH(payload interface{}, c *websocket.Conn) {
    type arbSSH struct {
        Data     string `json:"data,omitempty"`
        Port     int    `json:"port,omitempty"`
        Username string `json:"username,omitempty"`
        Password string `json:"password,omitempty"`
        Hostname string `json:"hostname,omitempty"`
        Type         string `json:"type,omitempty"`
    }
    marshalled, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        serverMsg.CreateAsError(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }

    //load, ok := payload.(arbSSH)
    var load arbSSH
    err = json.Unmarshal(marshalled, &load)
    if err != nil {
        serverMsg.CreateAsError(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf(err.Error()))
        return
    }

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: load.Username,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(load.Password),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", load.Hostname, load.Port), config)
    if err != nil {
        serverMsg.CreateAsError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    // Each ClientConn can support multiple interactive sessions,
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        serverMsg.CreateAsError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    if load.Type == "output" {
        fmt.Println("Recieved Output command")
        defer client.Close()
        defer session.Close()
        stdout, err := session.Output(load.Data)
        if err != nil {
            serverMsg.CreateAsError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
            return
        }
        serverMsg.Payload = struct {
            Data string `json:"data,omitempty"`
        }{string(stdout)}
    }
}

This implementation of go ssh creates a new ssh terminal for each command run, so prior to running each command I source the needed files and create the required environment variables to ensure that ros runs correctly. To demonstrate this format, an example command I might run looks like:
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=30 > /dev/null && source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash > /dev/null && source ~/example_ws/install/local_setup.bash > /dev/null && ros2 launch example example.launch.py

This format has worked for all other ros commands I have tried so far as I mentioned above. I retested the exact launch commands I sent via go in a regular SSH terminal connected to my robot and they work just fine, launching the expected nodes and displaying output.
I have tried adding '&' to the end of the command to make it run in the background, but that did not make it run correctly. I attempted using 'nohup' to run the command, however that also changed nothing.
I have done further testing on running launch files through ssh to try and see if the problem stems from interactivity. I discovered that when running the command directly from ssh instead of using an interactive ssh terminal, as follows:
ssh username@ip_address "export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=30 > /dev/null && source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash > /dev/null && source ~/example_ws/install/local_setup.bash > /dev/null && ros2 launch example example.launch.py"

I discovered that the command would run, displaying the correct ROS_INFO output on my ssh terminal, however when trying to check if that node was running on the robot, by running ros2 node list and ros2 topic list no corresponding node would be displayed. The ROS_DOMAIN_ID is the same on both the robot and the ssh terminal command. I am wondering if this behaviour might be connected to the problem I am facing, and if so how do I bypass it?

Do I understand correctly that your code logs in, spawns a command and then ends the SSH session? If yes, terminating the session also terminates the process tree associated with it. In this case, you might explore switching on so-called "lingering" (search for "linger" here) and systemd-run.

You might also want to look at nohup and terminal multiplexors such as tmux and screen.

Yeah I tried using nohup. tmux and screen, unfortunately they all give the same result. I will try enabling lingering now

@user25009967 I think the point is that these are all workarounds for getting ros launch working with a non-persistent ssh connection, which isn't a great idea. Making a systemd service would generally be the "right" solution here.

@BTables good suggestion, however it seems to lead to the same issue. I created a bash script that runs the launch command and sources everything, even when just running the bash script on its own I have the same issue, where it produces the correct output but there is no visible connection to ros2. The same  behaviour happens when I run the bash script via the service

The bash script i'm using:
#!/usr/bin/bash
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source /home/username/workspace/install/local_setup.bash
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=30
ros2 launch launch_test launch_test.launch.py

The service file I am using:
[Unit]
Description=test
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
User=username
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/theo/launch_test.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
The service starts up correctly, and I checked the output using journalctl and it is producing the correct output

But still nothing is displayed when running ros2 node info and ros2 topic info

@user25009967 Assuming the domain ID is correct, something is wrong with your actual node then; but without seeing the code it's impossible to say. I can vouch for the systemd approach because I've done this exact scenario with a ROS node before.

When launching the nodes by manually running the launch commands on an interactive terminal, even on an interactive ssh terminal, the node produces the correct output and can be found by running 'ros2 node list'. I will post the node below, however I have tested it pretty extensively and am sure that it works when launched normally. Were there any extra steps you took when making your node launchable via a service?

@BTables
my node looks like this:
`
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from std_msgs.msg import String
class launchTest(Node):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('launch_test')
    self.test_topic_pub = self.create_publisher(String, '/test_topic', 10)
    timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
    self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
    self.i = 0

`

`
def timer_callback(self):
msg = String()
msg.data = 'Hello World: %d' % self.i
self.test_topic_pub.publish(msg)
self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
self.i += 1
def main(args=None):
rclpy.init(args=args)
launch_test = launchTest()

rclpy.spin(launch_test)

launch_test.destroy_node()
rclpy.shutdown()
# end main customization

if name == 'main':
main()`

And my launch file looks like this
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='launch_test',
            executable='launch_test',
            name='launch_test'
        )
    ])



sorry for terrible formatting
